# Get string content of HTML input

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML form that will contain predefined values that the user will have to confirm by editing their contents, if needed.
I would like to perform a constant check so that the color background of every cell changes accordingly to its content.
For example, if the cell is empty, its background should be red. Later on I will add more check, for example if it contains the string "MISSING VALUE" it should be yellow and so on.

This is an example of my form and the code I'm trying to execute:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style type="text/css">
  table.first {
    display: table;
    table-layout: auto;
    float: none margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  
  .table_element {
    display: table-cell;
  }
</style>

<table class="first">
  <div class="table_element">
    <p style="text-align: center;">First Name:<br><input name="import_date_visit" id="subEmail" type="text" required size="25" onchange="checkFilled();" value="Claudio"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="table_element">
    <p style="text-align: center;">Last name:<br><input name="import_date_visit" type="text" required size="25" onchange="checkFilled();" value="MISSING VALUE"></p>
  </div>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function checkFilled() {
    var inputVal = document.getElementsByClassName("table_element");
    for (var i = 0; i < inputVal.length; i++) {
      document.writeln((i + 1) + ": " + inputVal[i].value);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < inputVal.length; i++) {
      if (inputVal[i].value == "") {
        inputVal[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
      } else {
        inputVal[i].style.backgroundColor = "white";
      }
    }
  }
  checkFilled();
</script>

</html>
```

What I don't understand is how to get the value of the string inside the `div` element. As you can see, I'm trying to print it as a debug, and I'm expecting to get the values `Claudio` and `MISSING VALUE`, but all I get is `undefined`. I suppose it should be pretty straightforward to get the content of a cell, so I assume I'm missing something very obvious.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Don't use `document.write()` or `.writeln()` for debugging. There are better options, e.g. `console.log()`

Comment: The structure of a html document is: `<html><head></head><body></body></html>` and in your case the [`<body>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/sections.html#elementdef-body) element is not optional

Comment: A `<div>` element has no `.value` property. Either query the DOM for the `<input>`s and then traverse up the DOM for the styling, or find the `<input>`s in the `<div>`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First find `input` element inside your div element and then use `value` property on it.

```js
    function checkFilled() {
        const divEle = document.getElementsByClassName("table_element");
       
        for(let i = 0; i < divEle.length; i++) {
            const inputVal = divEle[i].children[0].children[1];
            if (inputVal.value == "") {
              inputVal.style.backgroundColor = "red";
            } else if (inputVal.value == "MISSING VALUE") {
              inputVal.style.backgroundColor = "green";
            }
        }
    }
checkFilled();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    table.first{
        display: table;
        table-layout: auto;
        float:none
        margin-left: auto; 
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    .table_element{
        display: table-cell;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table class="first">
    <div class="table_element">
        <p style="text-align: center;">First Name:<br>
        <input name="import_date_visit" id="subEmail" type="text" required size="25" onchange="checkFilled();" value="Claudio" />
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="table_element">
        <p style="text-align: center;">Last name:<br><input name="import_date_visit" type="text" required size="25" onchange="checkFilled();" value="MISSING VALUE" /></p>
    </div>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: "`divEle[i].children[0].children[1];`" - sorry, but this is not modern JavaScript …

Comment: What do you mean by modern JavaScript, How do you write it other way, please let me know.

Comment: Are you talking about to use `childNodes` instead of `children`?

Comment: I mean, that you should not access children of an element by using indexes, but rather by giving the childs classes / id's and using `document.querySelector` or `document.querySelectorAll`

Comment: I understand your concern you are talking about best practices

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should always have a `body` element. Whenever you create anew HTML document, you should first paste in the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Scripts and stylesheets should go into the `head` section, and any content that should be visible to the user in to the `body` section. `<meta charset="utf-8">` should be always present - else non-ASCII characters will not be rendered correctly. Change `utf-8` to whatever encoding you use in your editor.

Secondly, `inputVal[i].value` tries to access the value property of the `p` element in side `.table_element` - but paragraphs don't have a value, so you get `undefined`.

Thirdly, `document.write` and `document.writeln` should not be used - if you want to show something to the user, write it into a HTML element, and if you want to print something for debugging purposes, use `console.log(...)`.

Lastly, `div`'s are not valid children of a `table` - only `thead`, `tbody` and `tr` are.

To find the input elements, you can use `document.querySelectorAll`. Following the working, modern code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style type="text/css">
    table.first {
      display: table;
      table-layout: auto;
      float: none;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
    
    .table_element {
      display: table-cell;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function checkFilled() {
      let inputElements = document.querySelectorAll(".table_element input");
      let outputElement = document.querySelector("#output");
      outputElement.innerHTML = "You entered : ";

      for (let [index, inputElement] of inputElements.entries()) {
        outputElement.innerHTML += " " + (index + 1) + " " + inputElement.value;
        if (inputElement.value == "") {
          inputElement.style = "background-color: red;";
        } else {
          inputElement.style = "background-color: green;";
        }
      }
    }
    window.addEventListener("load", checkFilled);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="table_element">
    <p style="text-align: center;">First Name :</p>
    <input name="import_date_visit" id="subEmail" type="text" required size="25" oninput="checkFilled();" value="Claudio">
  </div>
  <div class="table_element">
    <p style="text-align: center;">Last name :</p>
    <input name="import_date_visit" type="text" required size="25" oninput="checkFilled();" value="MISSING VALUE">
  </div>
  <p id="output">You entered : nothing yet</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's recommended to add your script under `body` in last, so that it improves the performance or load time.

Comment: "_It's recommended to add your script under body in last_" - can you provide a link where that's stated ?

Comment: https://betterexplained.com/articles/speed-up-your-javascript-load-time/ you can read the section `Optimize Javascript Placement`